# RuntimeError: Working outside of application context with Celery and Flask in Python

Tags: python, flask, runtime-error, celery, webhooks

I have read many different blogs explaining how to combine Flask and Celery. I've also read tons of stack questions on the subject. However, it has been days and I still don't manage to solve this "RuntimeError: Working outside of application context" and I don't know what I can do to solve the issue at this point.

The project is done as such :

- /application

  - __ init__
  - models
  - routes
  - tfidf_matching
- celery_worker
- config
- wsgi

I implemented my project to have a Factory architecture as done on this [article](https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-application-factory). Then, the celery implementation has been done to fit this Factory architecture as explained on this [article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern).

The HTTP request is handled in routes.py and will call a celery task to be done in the background. Meanwhile the app can continue to run and do other things. It will send a POST HTTP with another function  and when the celery task is done then it will send a POST HTTP of the celery result.

routes.py contains the following, I have reduced it to the important parts:

```
from flask import request, make_response, jsonify, copy_current_request_context
from flask import current_app as app
from application import tfidf_matching
import time
from application.models import db, Status
from app import cel

def snooze(maxTime):
    ...


@app.before_first_request
def default_values():
    ...

@cel.task
def tfidf(question):
    with app.app_context:
        answer = tfidf_matching.getMatchingSentence(question)
        ...
        return answer

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    req = request.get_json(force=True)
    ...
    if ... :
        user_input = req.get('queryResult').get('queryText')
        answer = tfidf.apply_async(args=[user_input], expires=60)
        ...
    snooze(4)
    response = {'followupEventInput': {'name': 'snooze'}}
    if ...:
        response = {'fulfillmentText': answer}
    return make_response(jsonify(response))
```

I have tried using @copy_current_request_context and with app.app_context to solve the error as suggested in other stack overflow questions but no success.

Celery is launched with the following command :

```
celery worker -A celery_worker.cel --loglevel=info
```

The celery_worker.py contains the following:

```
import os
from app.routes import tfidf
from application import cel, create_app

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
app.app_context().push()
```

I am not sure if it is necessary but in case I am also adding the init and wsgi content. Models is an SQLAlchemy database and this doesn't seem relevant so I will not add this part.

__ init__.py contains the following:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from celery import Celery
from config import config, Config

db = SQLAlchemy()

cel = Celery(__name__, broker=Config.broker_url, backend=Config.result_backend)


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    db.init_app(app)
    app.config.update(
        broker_url='redis://localhost:6379',
        result_backend='redis://localhost:6379',
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='postgresql://postgres:APG@localhost:5432/Dialogflow',
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS='None'
    )
    cel.conf.update(
        result_expires=3600,
    )
    cel.conf.update(app.config)
    with app.app_context():
        from . import routes
        db.create_all()
        return app
```

And wsgi.py contains the following:

```
import os
from application import create_app

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Finally, this is the stack trace :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Emma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\celery.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 495, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 289, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 509, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 531, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\celery\app\utils.py", line 373, in find_app
    sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 534, in symbol_by_name
    return imports.symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\imports.py", line 57, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\celery\utils\imports.py", line 111, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Emma\PycharmProjects\APG_Dialogflow\celery_worker.py", line 2, in <module>
    from application.routes import tfidf
  File "C:\Users\Emma\PycharmProjects\APG_Dialogflow\application\routes.py", line 21, in <module>
    @app.before_first_request
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 348, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 307, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 52, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

## Edit

By changing `from flask import current_app as app` as suggested by Miguel the Error disappears.

I changed the import to `from wsgi import app` in routes.py but this doesn't work. My app instance should be imported in another way but I don't know how

When running flask with : flask run
I get the following Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\emma\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Emma\PycharmProjects\APG_Dialogflow\wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
  File "C:\Users\Emma\PycharmProjects\APG_Dialogflow\application\__init__.py", line 28, in create_app
    from . import routes
  File "C:\Users\Emma\PycharmProjects\APG_Dialogflow\application\routes.py", line 6, in <module>
    from wsgi import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'wsgi' (C:\Users\Emma\PycharmProjects\APG_Dialogflow\wsgi.py)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have this in your code:

```
from flask import current_app as app
```

And then you use `app` in `@app.route` and `@app.before_first_request`.

This is incorrect, Flask has no way to figure out what is your application instance. What you need to do is use the real application instance instead of `current_app`.

You can use `current_app` inside a view function because Flask sets the app context for you, but you cannot use it in the global scope of your application.

**Update to the answer after your update:**

You now how a circular dependency problem. Note how the last stacktrace shows `wsgi.py`, going into `application/__init__.py`, then on to `application/routes.py` and finally back into `wsgi.py`.

A fairly common solution for this problem in Flask apps is to move the `from . import routes` in your `application/__init__.py` file all the way to the . bottom of the file. I believe that will remove the circular dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It seemed to have solved this error by replacing [from flask import current_app as app] to [from wsgi import app] when running celery. So what you pointed is indeed the error. However I don't know how to properly pass my app instance. Doing it the way I did with this import ends up in an error when running flask : ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'wsgi'. How would you pass the app instance as it is a necessary reference for app.route and app.before_first_request ?

Comment: Can you add the new stack trace to your question?

Comment: Yes, I added it under an Edit title !

Comment: I see the circular dependency indeed ! What do you mean to put [from . import routes] to the bottom of the file ? Right now the import is inside create_app(). Removing this import makes the webhook not found but the import error is not raised anymore so it is indeed the problem. But where else could the import be for it to still work ?

Comment: I cannot say for sure without seeing all your code, but why did you put this import inside the create_app function? Take it out of the function and move it all the way to the bottom of the file. That might help, hopefully!

Comment: This is how it is done in the blog/website linked in my question for SQLAlchemy (after the factory structure tutorial). Putting the import outside the method at the bottom doesn’t make it work unfortunately :/ this import with dB.create_all() seems key to make it work but well it also creates the circular import so idk what to do about it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206383/discussion-between-emma-vande-wouwer-and-miguel).